# Problems freeing memory in a copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, copy-constructor, delete-operator

I have this parent class

```
class Monster 
{
    char* nume;
    double hp;
    float* dmgAbilitati;
    int nrAbilitati;
}
```

with this copy constructor

```
Monster(const Monster& src)
    {
        if (nume != nullptr)
            delete[] nume;
        this->nume = new char[strlen(src.nume) + 1];
        strcpy_s(this->nume, strlen(src.nume) + 1, src.nume);
        this->hp = src.hp;
        this->nrAbilitati = src.nrAbilitati;
        if (dmgAbilitati != nullptr)
            delete[] dmgAbilitati;
        this->dmgAbilitati = new float[this->nrAbilitati];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->nrAbilitati; i++)
            this->dmgAbilitati[i] = src.dmgAbilitati[i];
    }
```

and I am asking if it is mandatory to use these statements

```
if (nume != nullptr)
            delete[] nume;
if (dmgAbilitati != nullptr)
            delete[] dmgAbilitati;
```

because I am trying to overload the pre/post-increment operator in this child class

```
class giantSpider : private Monster
{
    int durataStun;

.
.
.
const giantSpider operator++(int)
    {
        giantSpider aux(*this);
        durataStun++;
        return aux;
    }
}
```

and it throws an exception like in the image below(sometimes works tho),
and if I'm not including those statements, everything is fine.

I am using this constructor to initialize the parameters

```
Monster(const char* nume, double hp, int nrAbilitati, float* dmgAbilitati)
    {
        if (nume == nullptr)
            throw new exception("Nume invalid!\n");
        else
        {
            this->nume = new char[strlen(nume) + 1];
            strcpy_s(this->nume, strlen(nume) + 1, nume);
        }
        if (hp <= 0)
            throw new exception("Hp invalid!\n");
        else
            this->hp = hp;
        if (nrAbilitati <= 0 && dmgAbilitati == nullptr)
            throw new exception("nrAbilitati invalid sau dmgAbilitati invalid!\n");
        else
        {
            this->nrAbilitati = nrAbilitati;
            this->dmgAbilitati = new float[nrAbilitati];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrAbilitati; i++)
                this->dmgAbilitati[i] = dmgAbilitati[i];
        }
    }
```

and for the child:

```
giantSpider(const char* nume, double hp, int nrAbilitati, float* dmgAbilitati, int durataStun)
        :Monster(nume, hp, nrAbilitati, dmgAbilitati)
    {
        if (durataStun <= 0)
            throw new exception("Numar introdus invalid!\n");
        else
            this->durataStun = durataStun;
    }
```

and this is in main:

```
float v1[] = { 125,234.22,8643.3 };
giantSpider  g2("Ana", 1000, 3, v1, 3);
cout << g2 << ++g2 << g2++ ;
```

I have already overloaded the << operator.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6kiz.png

Comment: Are you doing this to practice the use of new/delete? If not, you should be using `std::string`...

Comment: 1) If you do `if (nume != nullptr) delete[] nume;` you'll get UB because `nume` is not initialized. 2) Calling `delete` on a `nullptr` is safe.

Comment: You shouldn't be freeing `nume` because you're (copy) constructing your `Monster` object.

Comment: Are you ever initializing `nume` to a non-trash value the first time you create a monster?

Comment: Raw pointers are usually unnecessary, and they certainly confuse many people who are not very experienced with C++.  Why have you chosen to use pointers?

Comment: I have a default constructor with all the parameter and i've initialized them all. I even tried to use the copy constructor separately and it works.

Comment: @bko00 A copy constructor does not use the default constructor. Any initialization you may do in a default constructor is not automatically applied to the copy constructor. You need to initialize the members again in the copy constructor. You may be confusing the copy constructor (which is only used to create new objects) with the copy assignment operator (which copies the value from one object onto an instance that already exists).

Comment: A copy constructor does not use the default constructor.  In C++, `if (p != nullptr) delete p;` is unnecessary to check for non-null because `delete` handles the nullptr case as a no-op.  Instead of any of that manual memory management, you should use `std::string` and `std::vector<float>` and perhaps `std::unique_ptr`.  They were created to help alleviate the annoyance of manual memory management.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: Sometimes the code works, sometimes not, without changing anything.

Comment: Don't return a const `giantSpider` from the post increment operator. You're returning a new object anyways, so there's little benefit in making it const. Furthermore the non-copy constructor isn't well implemented: If the constructor body throws, the destructor won't be run, but you may have allocated memory before you throw which can result in a memory leak. It's pretty simple to avoid this, if you put the allocated object under management of a object that is a member, such as `std::string` and `std::vector<float>` or at least `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` and `std::unique_ptr<float[]>`...

Answer (score 3):

These statements

```
if (nume != nullptr)
            delete[] nume;
if (dmgAbilitati != nullptr)
            delete[] dmgAbilitati;
```

do not make a sense because the data members `nume` and `dmgAbilitati` are not initialized yet. More precisely neither memory was allocated where they would point to.

So these statements invoke undefined behavior.